# Programming logic to group a users activities like Facebook

Tags: social-networks, database

So I am trying to develop an activity feed for my site. Basically If I `UNION` a bunch of activities into a feed I would end up with something like the following.

> **Chris** is now friends with **Mark**
>
> **Chris** is now friends with **Dave**

What I want though is a neater way of grouping these similar posts so the feed doesn't give information overload...

E.g.

> **Chris** is now friends with **Mark**, **Dave** and **4 Others**

Any ideas on how I can approach this logically? I am using Classic ASP on SQL server. Here is the `UNION` statement I have so far:

```
SELECT 
    U.UserID As UserID, L.UN As UN,Left(U.UID,13) As ProfilePic,U.Fname 
    + ' ' 
    + U.Sname As FullName, 'said ' 
    + WP.Post AS Activity, WP.Ctime
FROM
    Users AS U LEFT JOIN Logins L ON L.userID = U.UserID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    WallPosts AS WP ON WP.userID = U.userID WHERE WP.Ctime IS NOT NULL
UNION SELECT
    U.UserID As UserID, L.UN As UN,Left(U.UID,13) As ProfilePic,U.Fname 
    + ' ' 
    + U.Sname As FullName, 'commented ' 
    + C.Comment AS Activity, C.Ctime
FROM Users AS U 
LEFT JOIN Logins L ON L.userID = U.UserID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Comments AS C ON C.UserID = U.userID WHERE C.Ctime IS NOT NULL
UNION SELECT 
    U.UserID As UserID, L.UN As UN,Left(U.UID,13) As ProfilePic, U.Fname 
    + ' ' 
    + U.Sname As FullName, 'connected with <a href="/profile.asp?un='+(SELECT Logins.un FROM Logins WHERE Logins.userID = Cn.ToUserID)+'">' 
    + (SELECT Users.Fname 
    + ' ' 
    + Users.Sname FROM Users WHERE userID = Cn.ToUserID) 
    + '</a>' AS Activity, Cn.Ctime
FROM 
    Users AS U 
LEFT JOIN 
    Logins L ON L.userID = U.UserID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Connections AS Cn ON Cn.UserID = U.userID WHERE CN.Ctime IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Are you looking for help crafting your SQL query, or are you looking for high-level design help?

Comment: High level design help really  its the logic I cannot get my head around...

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to use a subquery to select only those messages and to group them: as long as all the messages begin with the same string ("Chris is not a friend with") you can easily select them and extract the friends' names. Then you just have to concatenate those and add it to your personal webpage.